# UWP Set Lockscreen/Wallpaper from Background Task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, windows-10, background-task

Is there any way to set the lockscreen or wallpaper image from a `Background Task`? I have the following code:

```
if (await UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.Current.TrySetWallpaperImageAsync(file)) {
    Debug.WriteLine("Live wallpaper set!");
} else {
    Debug.WriteLine("Live wallpaper failed to set...");
}
```

Which works when I execute normally in the app, but not when I execute from a `Background Task` -- a breakpoint after the first line never gets hit, indicating another sync/deadlock issue ([see my previous post on a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32731566/c-sharp-w10-uwp-backgroundtask-storagefile/32731990)). The fix in that thread also didn't work for me (it always returns `false`):

```
bool success = UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.Current.TrySetWallpaperImageAsync(file).GetResults(); // Try GetResults()... ALWAYS returns false

bool success = Task.Run(async () => {
    return await UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.Current.TrySetWallpaperImageAsync(file);
}).Result; // ALWAYS returns false...
```

Is there something I'm missing (maybe can't call `TrySetWallpaperImageAsync` from a `Background Task`)?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure if your if you're running a background task that its registered. 
And in the Run method and subsequent methods make sure to use

```
BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
```

And you don't have to use `.GetResults()` for `TrySetWallpaperImageAsync()` cause it returns a bool by default.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had an `async void` method which I wasn't `awaiting` in my `Run` method. Changed to `IAsyncOperation<bool>` with `AsyncInfo.Run` and everything works now. Rookie mistake :)